# Automatically highlight current chapter in Navigator

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice

Is there way to automatically highlight current chapter in Navigator?

Yes, there are at least two workarounds: (1) use "Chapter" field in Header of the pages or (2) Start every chapter as Section, so it's name would be visible in status bar.

But both these workarounds are not convenient. In documents with a lot of images I prefer Web Layout, so the Header will not be visible. Sections are also far from perfect solution.

Probably I overlook some another workaround or maybe there exists some plugin for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Navigator window, click on `Content View` (second button in the second row).

Comment: Big thanks. I also upvoted, but since my score is lesser then 15, my upvote is not visible currently.

Comment: Also, maybe you know why button `List Box On\Off` is always pressed? For some reason, I can't "unpress" it.

Comment: Thanks, your upvote is visible in my reputation :)   The List Box button works fine as a toggle for me. The window under it disappears when it's off. Press harder ... or ask a new question, with your version of LO